# how can modify python script var with node.js?

Tags: python, node.js

//   node.js file contain

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell',{mode:'binary'});
var pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');

// sends a message to the Python script via stdin 
pyshell.send('hello');


pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement) 
  console.log(message);
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit 
pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

//   my_script.py file

```
    # This program adds two numbers

num1 = 1.5
num2 = 6.3

# Add two numbers
sum = float(num1) + float(num2)

# Display the sum
print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))
```

//   in python file you see num1 and num 2 and sum formula

//    i wanna change num1 value to 5 or 6 ... with node.js can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1) Edit the file before running the python script : Load the file in node, parse it, and overwrite the value.

2) Call a node JS route from the python script running and make node return the new value from this route.

Hope this helps !